# context switch inside timer interrupt, unexpected compilation error

Tags: c++, timer, compiler-errors, interrupt, context-switch

I'm testing a context switch which is implemented in `dispatch()` function.
To my understanding, problem occurs when I invoke dispatch inside interrupt timer. It won't even compile if I do that! Strange is that if I implement dispatch just to invoke timer interrupt and timer to make context switch, it works perfectly. I've tried to make dispatch a macro or inline function, but the problem is the same - when I try to build it, some unexpected exception occurs?

Is this enough for you to tell me what's wrong?

```
class PCB{ // this class represents a thread
  public:
unsigned sp;
unsigned ss;
Status status;
Time kvant; // time slice
static PCB* running;

void createProcess(void (*body)());
};

PCB* PCB::running = 0;

void PCB::createProcess(void (*body)()){

unsigned* stek = new unsigned[1024];

st1[1023] =0x200; // PSW register with I flag setted to be 1
st1[1022] = FP_SEG(body);
st1[1021] = FP_OFF(body);

this->sp = FP_OFF(st1+1012); // space for registers ax,bx,cx,d,si,es,ds,di,bp
this->ss = FP_SEG(st1+1012);

this->status = NEW;
}

void interrupt timer(){
timer_counter--; 
if (timer_counter == 0) dispatch(); 

 else asm int 60h; // invoking the old routine
}

void interrupt dispatch(){
asm cli;
    asm {
        // store sp
        mov tsp, sp
        mov tss, ss
    }

    PCB::running->sp = tsp;
    PCB::running->ss = tss;

    cout<<"Context change!"<<endl;

    if(PCB::running->status !=END){
     PCB::running->status = READY;
     Scheduler::put(PCB::running);
    }
    PCB::running=Scheduler::get();
    PCB::running->status = RUNNING;

    tsp = PCB::running->sp;
    tss = PCB::running->ss; 

    timer_counter = PCB::running->kvant;

    asm {
        mov sp, tsp   // restore sp
        mov ss, tss
    } 

    asm sti;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it's written in c++ and compiler is BorlandC 3.1. And the code: